# Ignoring NA's in multiple regression

Tags: r

I have three data matrices `MatZ`, `MatX`, and `MatY`, where each column of matrix `Z`, `Y`, `X` corresponds to a set of observations for the same expression probe. For every column `i`, I want to regress `Z` against `X` and `Y`, i.e.

```
lm(MatZ[,i]~MatX[,i]+MatY[,i])
```

by looping over all `i` columns. The problem with this is that some columns of `MatX` are all `NA`'s. Therefore, I need some argument in `lm` that performs a linear regression of `MatZ[,i]` just against `MatY[,i]` when all elements of `MatX[,i]` are `NA` (i.e. leaving `MatX[,i]` out of the regression), while using both in the linear model when there are defined observations for `X`. As it stands, I get an error `0 (non-NA) cases in the lm call`.

Comment: I'm concerned that you are seem to be using `lm.fit` via a formula interface, and also that you seem to be unaware of the `na.action` argument to `lm`. Can you explain a bit?

Comment: na.action=na.omit resolves the problem as long as some elements in the column are not na. If the entire column consists of na's, then the error message listed above appears. So basically, I need lm to ignore one of the predictor variables entirely in this instance.

Comment: Ok, but that doesn't explain why you're attempting to use `lm.fit` via a formula when it does not support formulas. Or why you're using `lm.fit` at all, really.

Comment: Unfortunately, I was confusing two different function, I meant to just have lm

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution without using `if`. This combines the two predictor columns into a single matrix, and then only selects those columns that aren't all NA.

```
lapply(seq_len(ncol(MatZ)), function(i) {
    m <- cbind(MatX[, i], MatY[, i])
    keep <- colSums(matrix(!is.na(m), ncol=2)) > 0
    lm(MatZ[, i] ~ m[, keep])
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
MatZ <- matrix(rnorm(1000),nrow=100)
MatX <- matrix(rnorm(1000),nrow=100)
MatY <- matrix(rnorm(1000),nrow=100)

MatX[,2] <- NA
MatY[,4] <- NA

condlm <- function(i){
    if(sum(is.na(MatX[,i]))==dim(MatZ)[1])
        lm <- lm(MatZ[,i]~MatY[,i])
    else if(sum(is.na(MatY[,i]))==dim(MatZ)[1])
        lm <- lm(MatZ[,i]~MatX[,i])
    else
        lm <- lm(MatZ[,i]~MatX[,i]+MatY[,i])
}

lms <- lapply(1:dim(MatZ)[2], condlm)
lms
```

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping that there would be some argument within the lm function that would automatically skip over missing variables, so that I could avoid doing this via if-else.

Comment: I'm not sure why that would exist. It should remove variables due to colinearity, so you could preprocess your data by replacing anything that's a column of `NA`s with a column of `1`s, but that will give you basically the same result and use about the same amount of code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a non-robust alternate solution via mapply as a start (works if 1 of the matrices is incomplete).  I too think there's no harm in if () else, however.

```
MatW <- matrix(rnorm(16),nrow=4)
MatY <- matrix(rnorm(16),nrow=4)
MatZ <- matrix(rnorm(16),nrow=4)
MatW[ , 3] <- NA
is.na(MatW[ ,3]) # True
lm.help2 <- function (x, y, z){
  if (is.na(all(x))) lm(z ~ y)[1] else lm(z ~ x + y)[1]}
mapply(lm.help2, 
       split(MatW, col(MatW)), split(MatY, row(MatY)), split(MatZ, row(MatZ)))
# $`1.coefficients`
# (Intercept)           x           y 
# 0.5736469  -0.4142749  -0.6161875 
# 
# $`2.coefficients`
# (Intercept)           x           y 
# -0.3755538   0.1491310  -1.0966652 
# 
# $`3.coefficients` 
# (Intercept)           y # Only 1 variable in regression equation!
# 0.6374279  -0.8962027 
# 
# $`4.coefficients`
# (Intercept)           x           y 
# -1.1016562  -0.7240938  -0.5976613
```

Comment: ... what happens if `x` is fine, but `y` is all NA?